# Unable to build React-Native project in android studio

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

After `react-native init AwesomeProject` command, I'm trying to open the project in android studio. But android studio unable to detect the project.

Comment: Are you opening the project inside the Android directory created inside your react-native directory? Or the react-native directory?

Comment: Yes. I'm opening the android folder.

Answer (score 0):

You essentially tried to open a React Native project in Android Studio. You should open the `android` folder within your project.

Comment: Yes. I'm opening the android folder. Still not building the app.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine after deleting the platform and re-creating again.